# Year is out of valid range when passing pos_infin as timeout to timed_wait

Tags: c++, boost, boost-thread, condition-variable, boost-date-time

The following code reproduces the error:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "boost/thread.hpp"
#include "boost/date_time/posix_time/ptime.hpp"

int main()
{
    boost::condition_variable_any cv;
    boost::timed_mutex m;

    try {
        {
            boost::timed_mutex::scoped_timed_lock guard(m);
            cv.timed_wait(guard, boost::posix_time::ptime(
                                 boost::posix_time::pos_infin));
        }
    }
    catch(std::exception & e) {
        std::cout << "Error : " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "Done" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

On my system, using Visual Studio 2005 and Boost 1.43, this produces the following output:

```
Error : Year is out of valid range: 1400..10000
Done
```

I would expect it to deadlock, waiting for the condition variable to be notified for all eternity. This does not seem to be documented anywhere, and also I would expect `timed_wait` to accept any valid `ptime`. Am I doing anything wrong? Is this a bug, or are infinite timeouts just not intended?

Comment: Can't reproduce here on linux with 1.45.0. Could you try if this is fixed in 1.45.0?

Comment: I'll have install it first, so it will take a bit.

Comment: @chris: I checked, and the error happens with 1.45 too.

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y it does not reproduce for me using boost 1.45 on Mac OS X. +1 for the reproducer though.

Comment: reproduced with Visual Studio 2010 and boost 1.46.1

Comment: I suspect you may be the only person ever to try to do this. The error message appears to come from converting `pos_infin` to gregorian date. As such it's going to require a special case to make it work (substituting max_date_time for pos_infin). As to whether it is correct, if fixing it ever makes it onto anybody's to-do list they are not very busy.

Answer (score 2):

Use boost::posix_time::max_date_time and it'll work as expected.